# How to determine an instance method's corresponding class?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

for example, I have this code, (new style class):

```
class B:
    def func(self):
        # do something to instance of type B
        pass

class A:
   def __init__(self, random_variable):
       if random_variable > 0:
           self.func = B().func
       else:
           pass

   def func(self):
       # do something to instance of type A
       pass

a = A(random_variable)
```

How to determine whether `func` attribute of instance `a` binds originally to B or to A, without checking the value of random variable?

Comment: How about checking the `type()`? The type can reveal if it belongs to class B or Class A

Comment: Do you mean `self.func = B().func` instead?

Comment: @HenryYik in this example, yes, and I've corrected it. however the problem is irrelevant to whether func is an unbound method or bound method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the `__self__` attribute of the method, which stores the instance it is bound to, and then use `isinstance`:

```
baby = A(np.random.rand() - 0.5).func
if isinstance(baby.__self__, A):
    print("It's an A! Congratulations!")

elif isinstance(baby.__self__, B):
    print("It's a B...")

else:
    print("What...is this...?")
```

I would note, strictly speaking, though, `func` is *always* initially bound to `A.func`, since you modify it in `__init__`.